# FASTAPI app not working with GCP APP engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, fastapi

I am trying to deploy a fastAPI app with python 7 to the GCP app engine. After configuring the app.yaml file app is working fine with dev_server while using the command `dev_server app.yaml`. But after deploying the app using `gcloud app deploy` and followed by `gcloud app browser` I am getting an access URL.

After hitting the URL I am facing an error as below

[image]

Note - I am using a quick lab for learning the deployment. And things are working fine with flask app but not working with the FastApi app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you already used the `devapp_server` command in order to test your application and it works, as a suggestion in order to check why you are facing this issue, you can try to see your App’s logs in the [Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com) from GCP.

Also, can be checked with the [Logs Viewer](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/writing-application-logs#viewing_logs) and the console using the command line:

> gcloud app logs tail

Check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/testing-and-deploying-your-app) for further information about writing and viewing logs from your app.

Moreover I could find a tutorial about [Deploying FastAPI in AppEngine](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/deploying-fastapi-application-in-google-app-engine-in-standard-environment-dc061d3277a). Maybe it could help you to develop it through this way also.